# What are the differences between Akka and Netty besides their choice of language (Scala vs Java)?

Tags: java, scala, akka, netty

I would like to understand the differences between Akka and Netty. I understand you can use both from Scala and Java. I am more interested in knowing where Netty is better (if anywhere) and where Akka is better (if anywhere). Where do they overlap, in other words, in what areas can I use Akka and not Netty and vice-versa.

Comment: They have almost no overlap.  There are too many difference to mention.  What area are you interested in?

Comment: If someone can summarize in few sentences what are the main differences between the two that would be great. I thought they were both asynchronous network I/O frameworks, but it looks like I am wrong.

Comment: @chrisapotek in fact, akka utilizes netty, so likely your question is similar to "what is the difference between wheel and vehicle?"

Comment: @om-nom-nom I was tempted to say that Akka is akin to EJBs, and Netty a Socket.  But I was worried about getting lynched ;)

Comment: I hope people don't close this question as I believe it is a perfectly valid question that a lot of people will benefit from.

Answer (score 39):

Akka is a concurrency framework built around the notion of actors and composable futures, Akka was inspired by Erlang which was built from the ground up around the [Actor paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model).  It would usually be used to replace blocking locks such as synchronized, read write locks and the like with higher level asynchronous abstractions.

Netty is an asynchronous network library used to make Java NIO easier to use.

Notice that they both embrace asynchronous approaches, and that one could use the two together, or entirely separately.

Where there is an overlap is that Akka has an IO abstraction too, and Akka can be used to create computing clusters that pass messages between actors on different machines.  From this point of view, Akka is a higher level abstraction that could (and does) make use of Netty under the hood.